# How to Automate upload local file to google cloud bucket using java or node js

Tags: java, node.js, google-cloud-platform

Can anyone guide me to automate the process of uploading  a file to GCP bucket using Java or nodejs

Comment: Stack overflow is focused on helping developers with code. Your question would benefit from including a summary of the progress you've made in trying to solve this solution. Google provides extensive documentation on its SDKs: Here's [Cloud Storage for NodeJS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to do a bit more research to be honest, this is enough to get you started with nodejs. But it will require some investigation.

The easiest way to do this is probably to use the firebase SDK's, but you can also use the google cloud lib like below. You will need to install the shown library and configure it though. This is a nodejs example.

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a GC storage client
const storage = new Storage({
  // Follow the medium tutorial to understand this bit
  // You need to generate and save a service key 
  keyFilename: serviceKey,
  projectId: 'your project id',
})

async function uploadFile() {
  await storage.bucket('my-bucket').upload('~/Documents/myfile.txt', {
    // destination is the remote path of the file 
    destination: 'myfile.txt',
  });

  console.log('Uploaded');
}
// If calling within an async func, remember to await the below
uploadFile().catch(console.error);
```

[Storage file upload doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs)

[This medium article will really help you](https://medium.com/@olamilekan001/image-upload-with-google-cloud-storage-and-node-js-a1cf9baa1876)